# SQL Server : newline character

Tags: sql, sql-server, newline

I have a programming language that does not allow me to write queries on multiple lines. It has to be written all in a single line.

I am unable to send a `GO` command because it has to be in a new line..

So for example, this does not work:

```
insert into mytable (field1, filed2) values (1, 2), (3, 4); go
```

as it should be

```
insert into mytable (field1, filed2) values (1, 2), (3, 4); 
go
```

I've tried multiple things but none worked:

```
insert into mytable (field1, filed2) values (1,2),(3,4); \r go

insert into mytable (field1, filed2) values (1,2),(3,4); \r\n go

insert into mytable (field1, filed2) values (1,2),(3,4); $r$n go

insert into mytable (field1, filed2) values (1,2),(3,4); char(10) go

insert into mytable (field1, filed2) values (1,2),(3,4); char(13) go
```

Is there a way to write it inline, and have SQL Server use it as 2 different lines?

Comment: `GO` is *not* a T-SQL statement. It's a batch separator processed only by Management Studio and `sqlcmd` (and other things like that), and no, there is no way to send that without a newline. But normally, there is no need to either, if you're working outside tools -- simply issue a new command if you have to start a new batch. (If you don't have to start a new batch, separating statements with `;` works -- that *is* part of T-SQL.)

Comment: Is it so secret you cannot reveal the programming language?

Comment: Why not just insert all the rows in one go, rather than 5 separate statements? An `INSERT` that inserts 5 rows is actually significantly faster than an 5 `INSERT`s than insert 1 row each.

Answer (score 2):

`GO` is ***not*** part of the TSQL language. It is used and recognized only by SSMS and sqlcmd to cut your script into parts ("batches"), and then each part is compiled and run separately, one after the other.

The reason that SSMS and sqlcmd work this way this is that it makes it possible to have e.g. a CREATE TABLE statement, followed by INSERT statements for that table. The INSERT-part will only compile if the table already exists, and that will be the case only *after* the CREATE has been run.

It is OK to combine multiple INSERTs into one statement. When in doubt about where the next statement should start, you can add a semicolon (`;`) to mark the end of the previous statement.

Comment: The general gist is correct, but your example is not; it's legal to have a `CREATE TABLE` statement and an `INSERT` in that same table in the same batch, for reasons too interesting to fit in this comment. A better example would be statements that need to have a batch to themselves, like `CREATE VIEW`.